# How do I restart Waitress?

Tags: python, restart, waitress

I'm using Waitress to serve Python/Flask pages on CentOS.

I'm using an HTML template file in the templates folder.  When I change the HTML template file, and refresh the main page in my web app, the changes made in the template are not visible.

I'm assuming I need to restart Waitress to force the changes to the template file to be rendered.

So what is the correct way to restart Waitress?

I've done a fair bit of Googling for "restart waitress python" and "restart waitress python flask" but nothing useful is returned.